# Error when trying to log in using Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm getting the following error trying to login using the Laravel `Passport`:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key\InMemory cannot implement Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key - it is not an interface
```

I was wondering how can this error be solved?

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: whats your laravel version and passport version ?

Comment: version "laravel/passport": "^8.4"  the error actually occurs when generating the token

Comment: in the method  `$token = $ user-> createToken ('Authentication token') -> accessToken;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563793/error-lcobucci-jwt-signer-invalidkeyprovided-it-was-not-possible-to-parse-your  might be relevant